# How to remove namespace from Elixir Phoenix app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The Elixir Phoenix prefixes Controllers, Models and Views with the namespace. In my case it's the `CableWeb`, as my app called the `Cable`.

I would like to remove it, as my app is small and would be easier to work with without the namespace.

I tried to remove it, and rewritten the code below

```
scope "/", CableWeb do
  pipe_through :browser

  get "/", PageController, :index
end

...

defmodule CableWeb.PageController do
  use CableWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
end

...

defmodule CableWeb.PageView do
  use CableWeb, :view
end
```

as

```
scope "/" do
  pipe_through :browser

  get "/", PageController, :index
end

...

defmodule PageController do
  use CableWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
end

...

defmodule PageView do
  use CableWeb, :view
end
```

I also removed the `lib/cable_web` folder and moved its content into `lib` and updated the template root path from `lib/cable_web/templates` to `lib/templates`. I also searched the codebase for `namespace` keyword and deleted it.

**It works ok, except for the templates.**

It works if I put the template into `templates/index.html.eex` and render it as `render(conn, "index.html")`

But it won't work if I put it into `templates/page/index.html.eex` and render it as `render(conn, "page/index.html")` or as `render(conn, "/page/index.html")`.

```
Could not render "/page/index.html" for PageView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "lib/templates/*". The following templates were compiled
```

I can see it correctly finds the `PageView` and passes it to `render_to_iodata` as

```
Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata(PageView, "page/index.html", assing)
```

It **seems like the Phoenix didn't compiled** the `lib/templates/page/index.html.eex` template. It finds templates without subfolders `lib/templates/*` but not in the subfolders `lib/templates/**/*`.

**UPDATE**

I finally made it work by adding the `pattern` option to `Cable.view`

```
...
use Phoenix.View, root: "lib/templates", pattern: "**/*"
...
```

But it feels strange, why it worked before with namespace without `**/*` pattern, and when I removed the namespace it stopped working?

Comment: I believe you need `namespace: ""` or like because it [defaults to the first nesting in the module name](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#__using__/1) and `root` is [calculated accordingly](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.5.8/lib/phoenix/view.ex#L505-L506).

Comment: My suggestion- don't do it. It can cause name conflicts and a lot of headaches. If you need then just alias all you need and call it a day.